# Fetching columns that have multiple row values assigned to them (followers)

Tags: php, mysql

So Im trying to just make a demo which maps out a users followers, and in my chrome tab I would want to see the user id and below a list of all the followers with their id and name, but so far I am only getting one follower id per user even if a user has multiple followers.

php :

```
require_once("config.php");
class FollowerMockApi {
   public static function Select(){
  
        $db = new connect();
        $result = array();
        $result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM followers, user WHERE followers.follower_id = user.id
        ');



      $result->execute();
        while($OutputData = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                 $followers[$OutputData['user_id']] = array(
                        'id' => $OutputData ['id'],
                        'follower' => $OutputData ['name'],
                 );
        }
              return json_encode($followers);
    }
}
echo FollowerMockApi::Select();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `followers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `follower_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=70 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4


CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password_hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `profile_image` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
 `cover_image` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
 `verified` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: We don't know what your `followers` and `users` table look like, so we can't really help, but since you use the `user_id` as the index of `$followers` array, and you assign a single follower to each user, you can only have one follower per user. Try this instead: `$followers[$OutputData['user_id']][] = .....`. I can't tell whether this will work, but there is a chance.

Comment: That's nice, I didn't expect that. Also look at your query, you might want to use the more commonly used JOIN: `SELECT * FROM followers JOIN user ON user.id = followers.follower_id;`, and then only select the columns you actually use.

Comment: And while I am nitpicking: Why use plural in `followers` and singular in `user`? It is more consistent to use one or the other, so either `followers` and `users` or `follower` and `user`.